# C# select multiple items in listview

Tags: c#, listview, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, observablecollection

I have one ListView and one observableCollection. I put observableCollection into the listView. I want to know how can i select multiple items in the listview with an other observable collection ?

I try to do : `this.listView1.SelectedItems.Add(object);`

But it didn't work.

Someone know how can I do it ?

I'm programming an application to windows 8.1 so i use winRT

Comment: I think you will find you answer in this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83945/listview-multiple-selection

Basically you need to either initialise your this.listView1.MultiSelect = true; and then create the onSelected function that keeps a count of the indexes that are selected.

Comment: I don't know how can i do that.I just want selected multiple items into listview with programmation.

Answer (score 2):

Try as below

```
for (int i = 0; i < listObject.Length; i++)
   listView1.Items.FindByValue(listObject[i].id).Selected = true;
```

Comment: the method FindByValue() does not exist i'm programming to Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution to my problem.

I think that it's not perfect but it's worked.

```
ObservableCollection<Object> obsObject = CR.GetListObject(Id);
LV_LIST_OBJECT.SelectAll();
foreach(var Item in LV_LIST_OBJECT.Items)
{
   bool bFound = false;
   if(Item.GetType() == typeof(Object))
   {
       foreach(Object obj in obsObject)
       {
           if (((Object)Item).ID_Object == obj.ID_Object)
           {
               bFound = true;
               break;
           }
   }
   if(!bFound)
   {
       LV_LIST_Object.SelectedItems.Remove(Item);
   }
}
```